# Can't select DOM element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to perform the very simple task of selecting all of the `section`s in my DOM using jQuery, but for some reason `$sections` is null everytime I do the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="bl-main">
        <section>
        ...
        </section>
        <section>
        ...
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        Boxlayout.init();
    });
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var Boxlayout = (function() {
    var $el = $( "#bl-main" );
    var $sections = $el.children("section");
    ...
    // init function and more code down below
});
```

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I'm working on this project in Rails, so it's very likely that I've messed up some part of Rails. The HTML is located in `app/assets/views/static_pages.html.erb`, and the JS is located in `app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js`

Comment: Where is the JS code located compared to the HTML you are trying to query?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8D26t/. I would suggest you have an error elsewhere in your page.

Comment: Totally forgot to mention, but this is a Rails project which I'm fairly new to. The HTML is located in app/assets/views/static_pages.html.erb, and the JS is located in app/assets/javascripts/statick_pages.js.

Comment: I'd argue that the JS code is located before the HTML and thus you are trying to access elements that don't exist yet. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196) and http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ .

Comment: Your argument would be correct! It seems like I don't understand the inner-workings of rails well-enough. I copy pasted the code from the separate JS file to the bottom of my HTML file, and everything works as intended. Thanks you!

Comment: The HTML should be located in app/views/controller_name/static_pages.html.erb and not in app/assets/views/static_pages.html.erb. assets is to keep only stylesheets,js files and images.

Comment: Moved it there but still no luck. Currently only working if I copy all of the JS into a `<script>` tag at the bottom of my HTML file

Comment: Did you actually read the answer in the question I linked to? Put your code inside `$(function() { .... })`. Also see the jQuery tutorial I linked to. It explains all of that.

Comment: Yep, all of my code is inside the document.ready call. I've updated my original post with more code to hopefully make things a bit clearer